# Visualizing the count of one categorical variable with the hue of another variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset with mostly categorical columns and I want to visualize them against each other. I don't have any counts so I tried to use seabon with value_counts though it doesn't do the job.

The dataset samples is:

```
Gender     category     visitor
m          G            Y
f          G            Y
f          S            Y
m          S            N
m          G            N
m          G            Y
f          S            N


sns.boxplot(
x=customers["Gender"],
y=customers["Gender"].value_counts(),
hue=customers['category']
data=customers,
palette="coolwarm",
)
```

How can I visualize the count of m and f in a stacked barplot with the category as color fill?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should do it:

```
aux=df.groupby(['Gender','category']).count().reset_index()
sns.barplot(aux.Gender, aux.visitor, hue=aux.category)
```

You could change column names to better fit what you're looking to plot